# Ahead of Time Compilation for Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, graalvm, ahead-of-time-compile

I have been trying to find a way to achieve **Ahead of Time compilation** for the Cassandra service (Which does some JIT Compilation by default).

I see that Cassandra has been written in Java and it is open-source which has clear instructions to build and run the service from the source (https://blog.pythian.com/how-to-build-your-very-own-cassandra-4-0-release/)

I also can see there are a few popular options that can help achieve Ahead of Time Compilation for Java Programs (Ex: https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/native-image/ a very popular choice)

But I wasn't able to find any resource that can guide me to perform AOT for Cassandra, If there is something that can help me perform AOT for Cassandra, Please guide me.